# How to configure pubsub_destination in Transcoder API of GCP

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-transcoder

Using [Google Transcoder API](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs) with Golang, we would like to get a pub/sub event when a job finishes. [The doc](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/create-pub-sub) mentions to configure `pubsub_destination` but I couldn't find a way to configure it when using [preset/web-hd template id](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/f70c0ade8d6cd8759a9d1d702128c3c3aec4b2e5/media/transcoder/create_job_from_preset.go#L48).

Do we need to specify [our own JobConfig](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/9974e71adebe65de4fed4ddcc9d0cdbfa00f556a/media/transcoder/create_job_template.go#L45) to specify pubsub?  Was hoping that we would be able to just add `pubsub_destination` to the `preset/web-hd` template's config.

Comment: You need to specify the `pubsub_destination` on your [Job Template Config](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/9974e71adebe65de4fed4ddcc9d0cdbfa00f556a/media/transcoder/create_job_template.go#L45).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can confirm that you need to **specify** the `pubsub_destination` on your **[Job Template Config](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/9974e71adebe65de4fed4ddcc9d0cdbfa00f556a/media/transcoder/create_job_template.go#L45)** in order to call the `Job Template ID`.