# How to add PubSub Destination while creating a job using preset "preset/web-hd" using google cloud transcoder-api?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-transcoder

I am converting a video, uploaded to cloud storage using a signed URL, using Transcoder API. I have written a cloud function that is triggered with write operations on the bucket. Everything is working fine but I need to get a notification when the conversion is completed. I am creating the job to convert the vid using the following code. I am trying to follow the solution proposed in this answer [Google Cloud Platform: Convert uploaded MP4 file to HLS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70124737/google-cloud-platform-convert-uploaded-mp4-file-to-hls-file)

```py
    def create_job_from_preset(project_id, location, input_uri, output_uri, preset):
    """Creates a job based on a job preset.

    Args:
        project_id: The GCP project ID.
        location: The location to start the job in.
        input_uri: Uri of the video in the Cloud Storage bucket.
        output_uri: Uri of the video output folder in the Cloud Storage bucket.
        preset: The preset template (for example, 'preset/web-hd')."""

    client = TranscoderServiceClient()

    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"
    job = transcoder_v1.types.Job()
    job.input_uri = input_uri
    job.output_uri = output_uri
    job.template_id = preset
    job.ttl_after_completion_days = 1
    job.config = transcoder_v1.types.JobConfig(
        PubsubDestination={
            topic_name=f"projects/{project_id}/topics/testing"
        }
    )
    response = client.create_job(parent=parent, job=job)
    print(f"Job: {response.name}")
    return response
```

The following snippet in the above code is not working

```py
    job.config = transcoder_v1.types.JobConfig(
        PubsubDestination={
            topic_name=f"projects/{project_id}/topics/testing"
        }
    )
```

I have viewed the following but couldn't find any solution.

https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/create-pub-sub

[How to configure pubsub_destination in Transcoder API of GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71591447/how-to-configure-pubsub-destination-in-transcoder-api-of-gcp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot not define any configuration on your `JobConfig` on your code if you are creating a job from a **preset** or **template** since the [preset and template](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/concepts/overview#job_template) will already populate the `JobConfig` for you.

As an alternative, you may [create job using an ad-hoc configuration](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/samples/transcoder-create-job-from-ad-hoc) and then define **PubsubDestination** as shown on below code:

*Note that I also corrected the syntax in using the `PubsubDestination`*

```py
from google.cloud.video import transcoder_v1
from google.cloud.video.transcoder_v1.services.transcoder_service import (
    TranscoderServiceClient,
)


def create_job_from_ad_hoc(project_id, location, input_uri, output_uri):
    """Creates a job based on an ad-hoc job configuration.

    Args:
        project_id: The GCP project ID.
        location: The location to start the job in.
        input_uri: Uri of the video in the Cloud Storage bucket.
        output_uri: Uri of the video output folder in the Cloud Storage bucket."""

    client = TranscoderServiceClient()

    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"
    job = transcoder_v1.types.Job()
    job.input_uri = input_uri
    job.output_uri = output_uri
    job.config = transcoder_v1.types.JobConfig(
        elementary_streams=[
            transcoder_v1.types.ElementaryStream(
                key="video-stream0",
                video_stream=transcoder_v1.types.VideoStream(
                    h264=transcoder_v1.types.VideoStream.H264CodecSettings(
                        height_pixels=360,
                        width_pixels=640,
                        bitrate_bps=550000,
                        frame_rate=60,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            transcoder_v1.types.ElementaryStream(
                key="video-stream1",
                video_stream=transcoder_v1.types.VideoStream(
                    h264=transcoder_v1.types.VideoStream.H264CodecSettings(
                        height_pixels=720,
                        width_pixels=1280,
                        bitrate_bps=2500000,
                        frame_rate=60,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            transcoder_v1.types.ElementaryStream(
                key="audio-stream0",
                audio_stream=transcoder_v1.types.AudioStream(
                    codec="aac", bitrate_bps=64000
                ),
            ),
        ],
        mux_streams=[
            transcoder_v1.types.MuxStream(
                key="sd",
                container="mp4",
                elementary_streams=["video-stream0", "audio-stream0"],
            ),
            transcoder_v1.types.MuxStream(
                key="hd",
                container="mp4",
                elementary_streams=["video-stream1", "audio-stream0"],
            ),
        ],
        pubsub_destination=
            transcoder_v1.types.PubsubDestination(
                topic=f"projects/{project_id}/topics/your-topic"
            ),
    )
    response = client.create_job(parent=parent, job=job)
    print(f"Job: {response.name}")
    return response
```

Output of my testing:
[image]

Other alternative is to [create your own job template](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/how-to/job-templates#create_job_templates) and then use it in your `template_id` so that you don't have to always define `PubsubDestination` in your code.

Comment: Hi @scott-b when I pass the video file without audio following error is displayed [Audio Missing](https://cloud.google.com/transcoder/docs/troubleshooting#audio-missing). Is there any workaround to bypass this requirement of having audio?

Comment: As of now, the transcoder API really requires an audio on the video file. Right now there is already a feature request created for this in this link https://issuetracker.google.com/211671037. You can star the public issue tracker feature requests and add ‘Me too’ in the thread. This will bring more attention to the request as more users request support for it.

Comment: Please have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72828010/how-to-make-video-or-audio-optional-in-transcoder-api
If you can help me out that would be great.